# How do I get cURL errors to go into the correct log file?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, logging, curl

I have a website running using Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.3.10, and cURL 7.2.00. The relevant portions of the apache config is below, and you will notice that errors are sent to `www.example.com_error.log`.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    # *snip*

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I use cURL from within PHP and turn verbose logging on using `curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` the output from cURL goes into Apache's `error.log` instead of the custom logfile I defined above. Why is this, and how can I get cURL's output to go into the correct log file?

Answer (score 2):

Per some answers to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176/error-log-per-virtual-host), php logs to the default Apache server log (error.log) as you've already noticed.  You can set the php log settings like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    # *snip*

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com_access.log combined

    php_flag log_errors on
    php_flag display_errors on
    php_value error_reporting 2147483647
    php_value error_log ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Alternatively, one answer in that SO question mentioned unsetting the `error_log` directive completely in php.ini to log to the relevant virtual host's logs, e.g. `example.com_error.log`.

Comment: Nope, I'm still getting cURL output in `error.log`, and this occurs even if I unset `error_log` in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

According to [curl documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), You can set log file location with CURLOPT_STDERR.

See complete example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868808/make-curl-output-stderr-to-file-or-string#14087761)